# Convert SQL statement into R code

Tags: sql, r

I need to apply following SQL code into R.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, COUNT(1) AS newcol, 
SUM(othercol) AS newcol2, SUM(othercol*othercol2) AS newcol3 FROM df;
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
WHERE 'some conditions'
```

I understand how `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(1)`, `SUM()` and `AS()` works  individually but not as a whole like in the code above, mainly how `COUNT(1)` and `SUM()` are working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 5):

As the OP didn't provide a reproducible example, the following `sql` syntax works (using `sqldf`)

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select col1, col2, COUNT(1) as newcol, 
       sum(othercol) as newcol2 
       from df 
       where col1 = 1 
       group by col1, col2")
#  col1 col2 newcol      newcol2
#1    1    a      2 -0.009295454
#2    1    b      2 -0.164004051
```

---

The above can also be done using `R` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[col1==1, .(newcol=.N, newcol2 = sum(othercol)), .(col1, col2)]
#   col1 col2 newcol      newcol2
#1:    1    a      2 -0.009295454
#2:    1    b      2 -0.164004051
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(col1 == 1) %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    summarise(newcol = n(), newcol2 = sum(othercol))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(1:4, each = 4), col2 = rep(letters[1:2], 
  each = 2), othercol = rnorm(16), othercol2 = runif(16))
```

Comment: I tried with sqldf but I got some errors than can't fix yet also I have tried use dpply of plyr package but I was not quite sure.

Comment: @Cdives I provided a reproducible example and it works for both `sqldf` and data.table.

Comment: @Cdives also added a `dplyr` method